# shell script for getting the line count of all part files in hdfs

Tags: bash, shell, apache-spark, data-analysis, data-cleaning

I have a set of part files in hdfs in the below structure:

```
/folder1/folder2/daily_AB20180910.csv
/folder1/folder2/daily_BC20180910.csv
/folder1/folder2/daily_CD20180910.csv
```

daily_AB20180910.csv, daily_BC20180910.csv etc are folders inside which there are part files in the form of : part-00000, part-00001 etc.

Now, I wanted a file that gives me the line count of all the part files in the following format:

```
AB20180910 - 1000
BC20180910 - 2000
CD20180910 - 4000
```

To achieve this, I have manually used a command like this:

```
echo - 'AB20180910 ' -~hadoop fs -cat /folder1/folder2/daily_AB20180910.csv/* | wc -l >> count.txt &
```

This works but was wondering, if I could use loop or probably a scala script to iterate through file names and achieve the result. Please suggest

Comment: spark-shell with script can be used

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the files using a `for` loop and use String Substitution to get the name of the file. The following should work in bash:

```bash
for file in $(hdfs dfs -ls /folder1/folder2/*.csv | awk '{print $8}')
   # Store count in a variable
   count=$(hdfs dfs -cat ${file} | wc -l)
   # Regex to extract ABC from daily_ABC.csv
   filename=$(echo "${f##*/}" | grep -oP 'daily_\K([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(?=.csv)')
   echo "${filename} - $count"
done
```